# A domain of a function cancels its asymptotes?

Tags: calculus

Consider the following two functions:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \\
g(x) = \sin(x) \cdot (1 + \cos(x))
$$
Both are defined with a domain of $\{x \in [0,2\pi]\}$.

Is it valid to say that the first function approaches an asymptote at $x = 0$ ?
Is it valid to say that the first function approaches an asymptote at $y = 0$ ?
About the second function, I assume that anyway it doesn't have asymptote (OR - should I actually say that they have infinite asymptotes at $ (-1 \le x \le 1) $ ??)

Is it valid to ignore the domain when calculating the asymptotes?

*Edit:*

Generally speaking, when a domain for a function is **given** - must I limit my calculation to the image that is the result of that domain?  (The first function is defined also for $ x \gt 2\pi$)

Comment: You don't have $f(x)$ defined at $x=0$.  By "asymptote" one often means a line that the graph of a function approaches but never touches.  In that sense the function $f(x)$ has a "vertical asymptote" at $x=0$.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, I corrected my sentence.

Comment: Thanks, but to be clear, is the *domain* for $f(x)$ really given as $[0,2\pi]$?  It seems you were asked about $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ separately; there's no "interaction" between the two functions as far as I can tell.

Comment: @hardmath Indeed, you are correct. But I intentionally attached the domain for both functions in order to understand this issue better.

Comment: If you want to extend the domain of $f(x) = 1/x$ to $[0,2\pi]$ then you'll need to define it at $x=0$.  While $f(x) = 1/x$ has a natural domain, $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, where both a vertical and a horizontal asymptote exist, restricting $f(x)$ to an interval $x \in [1,2]$ eliminates both asymptotes (since the graph no longer "approaches without touching" either of them.

Comment: This isn't really relevant to the question, but it looks a bit funny when you write $\{x \in [0,2\pi]\}$ instead of simply $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Why's that..? I need to specify that the parameter `x` belongs to that range. Isn't that what every pedantic mathematician would write?

Comment: Just write $D_f = [0,2\pi]$. The fact that the variable is called $x$ in the formula $f(x)=1/x$ is irrelevant. By definition, $[0,2\pi]$ *means* $\{ x \in \mathbf{R} \colon 0 \le x \le 2 \pi] \}$, so writing $\{ x \in \mathbf{R} \colon x \in [0,2\pi] \}$ is like writing $\{ x \in \mathbf{R} \colon x \in \{ t \in \mathbf{R} \colon 0 \le t \le 2 \pi] \} \}$, which is correct but rather unreadable in comparison to the simple $[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\frac1x$ has a vertical asymptote $x=0$, because the denominator is zero for this value of $x$, and has a horizontal asymptote $y=0$, because $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$.

The function $g(x)=\sin x\cdot(1+\cos x)$ has no asymptotes at all. It has no vertical asymptote, because the function is not rational, and it has no horizontal asymptote because the limits $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}g(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ are not defined.

Comment: Is this true also for a domain of $\{x \in [0,2\pi]\}$..?

Answer (score 1):

There is some squishiness in the definition of *asymptote*, so it's best to pay close attention to what the authors of a paper or book require.

The definition I give in the comments above is a line that the graph of a function approaches "without touching".  This is a conservative case, one that I'd expect general agreement constitutes an asymptote.  However see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) for variations.

The term was coined by Apollonius of Perga, but he used it simply to mean a line that did not touch (intersect) a curve.  So the notion of "approaching" (so central to modern developments, esp. calculus and analysis) was not present there.

At the other extreme one can forget whether there are points of intersection between the curve and the line (asymptote) and focus on having the line be "tangent to the curve at infinity".  This imposes a condition on nearness of the curve and line (or ray, in some cases) at sufficient distance from the origin (closer to "infinity").

According to the Wikipedia article, some authors allow for only a finite number of intersections between the curve and the asymptote.  Thus $y = (\ln x) e^{-x}$ on $(0,+\infty)$ could be said (by these authors) to have a horizontal asymptote $y = 0$ despite one point of intersection at $x=1$.

When you have a bounded curve, such as a circle, the modern usage doesn't allow us to have asymptotes, since the curve only exists within a bounded region and does not approach infinity in any direction.

So if you limit a bounded function to a bounded interval, then you will also not have asymptotes for this same reason.  The curve does not have points outside a bounded region, so it cannot approach a line or a ray at infinity.

A curve like $y = \sin x$ does not have an asymptote, vertical or horizontal.  Setting aside the issue of allowing for infinitely many intersections, the sine curve does not approach any horizontal (or vertical) line at infinity, but rather oscillates back and forth around $y = 0$, and that does not an *asymptote* make!

Comment: When you wrote "bounded interval", is that equivalent to a "domain" ?

Comment: I had in mind your restricting a function to an interval, so that by construction it is only defined there.  The set of arguments for which a function is defined is its *domain*.  You can choose a subset of the real line to be a domain, so you might have bounded intervals, unbounded intervals, or domain's that are not connected (e.g. define $y = \sin x$ only for rational arguments $x$).